# If statement searching for a specific character

Tags: java

So I'm making a fraction calculator and I have one last part to figure out. For calculations that involve multiplying by 0, the final answer must always be 0. Due to my code I always end up with something like 0/1 or 0/5, so it always has a denominator. I want to return the answer without that denominator, but I'm not sure how to write my if statement. Here's my attempt at trying to print the 0 without the denominator.

```
if (reducedAnswer.charAt(0) == 0) {
        return reducedAnswer.substring(0, 1);
    }
```

I'm not quite sure how to modify that if statement to check if the first character of the answer is 0 so I can remove the unwanted parts. Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like you are using a string to represent a fraction? You should use two integers.

Comment: The assignment requires that I return the answer as a string

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to check whether the numerator is zero _before_ you convert the fraction to a `String`, and just return `"0"` for your output if it is?

Comment: didn't think about it that way. thanks, will do

Answer (score 2):

You need a `char` literal, change

```
if (reducedAnswer.charAt(0) == 0) {
```

to

```
if (reducedAnswer.charAt(0) == '0') {
```

**or** use `String.startsWith` like

```
if (reducedAnswer.startsWith("0")) {
```